# How to align sideways multiple html images using pl/sql for loop

Tags: html, plsql, oracle-apex

I have sample procedure code which is sending email via apex_email.

It sends email on birthdays and shows images of people with birthdays.

I need to modify code such that the images which are currently showing with emp name come row wise.
I have shared part of code that needs to be modified.

Currently with this code images are coming one below the other.

i.e. If there are 5 employees with birthdays, the first row would show max 3 images and then move to next tr/row.
If there are 3 employees, they would remain in first row.

CODE TO MODIFY:

```
 <h2 style="color: #008000;font-family:Verdana">Greetings </h2>

<td background="IMG" width="800" height="800" valign="top">

 <!--[if gte mso 9]>

  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:1069px;height:1000;">

   <v:fill type="tile" size=100%,100% src="IMG" />

    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">

 <![endif]-->

  <div >

  <h2 style="color: red"> <b> <i>'||to_char(i.sysdate,'DDth MONTH')||' </i> </b></h2>

   <td>';

   for j in(select e.emp_name,e.empid from emp e where substr(to_date(e.EMP_BDAY_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY'),1,6) = substr(to_date(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY'),1,6) )

 LOOP

    l_body_html2 := l_body_html2||' <div class="content">  <img width="120" height="120" style="vertical-align:middle" src="https://myserver.net/birthday/image/?FILE_ID='||j.empid||'" /> </div> <p style="color: red"> <b>'||'Dear '||j.emp_name||'</b></p>';   

  end loop;

  l_body_html := l_body_html||l_body_html2||

  </td>  

  </div>

  <!--[if gte mso 9]>

    </v:textbox>

   </v:rect>

   <![endif]-->

  </td>

  </tr>
```

For loop needs to be modified to display images, max 3 in a row.

EDIT: I tried this logic but the images are still coming one below another:

```
  <div >

  <h2 style="color: red"> <b> <i>'||to_char(i.sysdate,'DDth MONTH')||' </i> </b></h2>

   <td>'; begin v_count:=1;

   for j in(select e.emp_name,e.empid from emp e where substr(to_date(e.EMP_BDAY_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY'),1,6) = substr(to_date(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY'),1,6) )

 LOOP

    l_body_html2 := l_body_html2||' <div class="content">  <img width="120" height="120" style="vertical-align:middle" src="https://myserver.net/birthday/image/?FILE_ID='||j.empid||'" /> </div> <p style="color: red"> <b>'||'Dear '||j.emp_name||'</b></p>';   

if MOD(v_count,3)=0 then
l_body_html2 := l_body_html2|| '<br/>"';
end if;
v_count := v_count+1;
  end loop;
end;
  l_body_html := l_body_html||l_body_html2||

  </td>  

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MOD function to know when to print the line break:

Example:

```
declare
  v_count number;
begin
  v_count := 1;
  for e in employees loop
    v_body := v_body || '<img src="https://... />"'; 
    if MOD(v_count, 3) = 0 then   // every 3 items, it will print the line break
      v_body := v_body || '<br />"'; 
    end if;
    v_count = v_count + 1;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: ok, i tried but images are still coming one below another.

Comment: I have edited post nd at end tried your code, but images are still coming one below another. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Could it be a restriction with outlook or the code needs to be amended?

Comment: First of all, you should know what your html should look like so you can see what your code is missing.
Your line break doesn't need to be a br, it can be a div or even your entire loop could be a table.
For outlook, or gmail, it is best to use tables to organize how the html will look.